# I cannot get path written in database it gives me another path which is related with server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I tried to get image Path from database with using eval but in cs part I get different path name.

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" Value='<%#Eval("Path")%>' runat="server" />
        <img alt="image" style="text-align: center" src="<%#Eval("Path")%>" /></a><asp:CheckBox
            ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
        <br></br>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and in .cs part I tied to get this path value but it brings me very different datapath

```
   foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
    {
        CheckBox ch = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("CheckBox1");
        HiddenField hf = (HiddenField)item.FindControl("HiddenField1");
        if (ch.Checked)
        {

            Image_BLLcs ibll = new Image_BLLcs();
            File.Delete(hf.Value);
            ibll.Delete(hf.Value);

        }
```

how can I solve these problem, can you help me?

for example
in my database path is equal `image/images (3).jpg`
but when I execute this code it shows this  `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\image\images (3).jpg` as a path.

Comment: You code looks fine. What do you mean by `different datapath`? Please give us example.

Comment: for example in my database path is equal image/images (3).jpg but when I execute this code it shows this 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\image\images (3).jpg' as a path.

Comment: Replace HiddenField with Literal for testing. Then what value do you see in browser and what value do you get in `File.Delete(literal.Text);`

Comment: but I want to hide it thats why I am using hiddenfield

Comment: I said `for testing`, so that you know which code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Server.MapPath and  it solved my problem

```
        File.Delete(Server.MapPath(hf.Value));
        ibll.Delete(Server.MapPath(hf.Value));
```